"AssertionError: settings.yaml file not found" in pynest
I am facing the following issue:
File "/home/rugain/Documents/repos/sap_integration_api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nest/cli/click_handlers.py", line 63, in create_nest_module
    db_type, is_async = get_metadata()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rugain/Documents/repos/sap_integration_api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nest/cli/click_handlers.py", line 8, in get_metadata
    assert setting_path.exists(), "settings.yaml file not found"
AssertionError: settings.yaml file not found

when running the following command:
pynest g module -n <any-module-name>


This file is used to configure the nest server.
Lets call it pynest_settings.yaml
config:
    db_type: null
    is_async: false

If you are struggling with this s***, use the following command:
cp pynest_settings.yaml <your_env>/lib/<your-python-version>/site-packages/nest/settings.yaml

